# Python unittest discovery can not import source code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-unittest

I am using Python unittest integrated in VSCode for test. I have directory like this

```
project_root/
  src/
    module/
      __init__.py
      a.py
  test/
    module/
      __init__.py
      test_a.py
```

The `test_a.py` has import `from module.a import SomeClass`

And I have args

```
"-v",
"-s",
"./test",
"-p",
"test*.py"
```

When run test discovery it fails and raises `ModuleNotFound` or `Can not import` the module or classes in `a.py`

PS: I have set the `PYTHONPATH` in `settings.json` and both code analysis and program launch works fine. But it seems does not help with `unittest` plugin. And one concern is that both `src`, `test` has the module named `module` and I am not sure this matters.

How to make it work?

Update: Seems it is a name conflict issue and unittest_discovery could not handle this. After I change the args to `-s ./test/module` it could import the src modules.

Comment: Can you move your test_a.py and a.py down a directory?

Comment: @daemon If you mean `test/module/submodule/a.py`, it does not work

Comment: You need to put an empty __init__.py file in the folder with your modules

Comment: @daemon I edited the question. I have it and I just omitted it before... I think if you do not have the `__init__.py` you could not discover the test, but not discovered but have import error.

Comment: Can you show us what is in you main.py

Comment: If you do not have the __init__.py it will not import the module

Comment: @daemon Yes this is what I mean. And by the way I added the import code.

Comment: When you run test discovery, what is the current working directory?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I run it by VSCode Test Refresh. From the log VSCode says it is the project_root

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think it only discovers the package in `test` but not `src`, although they have same package name in subdir

Comment: Look at the error message. It's discovering the test just fine. The source packages *aren't "discovered"*; that's not how test discovery  works. They are imported, because the point of the test code is to *use* that code, and the way you use external code is to `import` it. The error message is clearly telling you that *that `import`* failed, and the reason it fails is that the `src` directory isn't a place that Python imports modules (and packages) from automatically - it has to be in `sys.path`, which happens by any of the normal mechanisms.

Comment: It's the same, in other words, as if you had tried to use `from module import a` from the interpreter prompt, starting from some arbitrary unrelated location on your hdd/ssd. Run from `src/`, or tell VSCode to set up PYTHONPATH appropriately, or install the package (preferably to a virtual environment) before testing.

Comment: Adding in ```-s ./test/module``` to my command worked, thanks a lot for adding that in to your question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to configure the `PYTHONPATH` in the `.env` file.

> An example of when to use PYTHONPATH would be if you have source code
> in a src folder and tests in a tests folder. When running tests,
> however, those tests can't normally access modules in src unless you
> hard-code relative paths.
>
> **To solve this problem, you could add the path to src to PYTHONPATH by**
> **creating an .env file within your VS Code workspace.**
>
> ***PYTHONPATH=src***

Because

> When the terminal settings are used, PYTHONPATH affects any tools that
> are run within the terminal by a user, as well as any action the
> extension performs for a user that is routed through the terminal such
> as debugging. **However, in this case when the extension is performing**
> **an action that isn't routed through the terminal, such as the use of a**
> **linter or formatter, then this setting will not have an effect on**
> **module look-up.**

You can refer to the [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_use-of-the-pythonpath-variable) for more details.

Comment: I read the official doc and your answer. The description matches perfectly with my issue. But... I follow the steps and even restart the VSCode, but no luck

Comment: @Litchy What's the result of `pprint(sys.path)` in the test_a.py when you run the test?

Comment: @Litchy What's the value of `sys.path`? You can debug the test to get the value of it.

Comment: `sys.path` has the src directory. And overall it includes: current test package dir, src code dir, and some python lib dir (site-packages)

Comment: @Litchy You can clarify  it clearly: `from src.module.a import SomeClass` Or Could you rename the `Module` under `src` to something others? Because when the `test folder path` before the `src folder path`, It will choose the `test.module` first. Or

Comment: @Litchy Sorry for being late, have you solved the problem?

Comment: So far, no... The import is explicit import like you suggest. And the `Module` name is suspicious I think (like both of us mentioned) but I could not change it because of our project regulation. I am still trying to find the logic of unittest discovery mechanism under the hood. And I think PyCharm could get this work because I migrated from PyCharm to VSCode and did not discover this issue before.

Comment: I insert the `print(sys.path)` to the `unittest_discovery.py` of my VSCode calls. It seems just fine. The src dirs are in it. But the test just could not import the src packages... I am trying to upgrade VSCode....

Comment: I have a work around now and updated in answer. It is a naming issue I suppose. Our doubt is right.

Comment: Have a similar issue with `PYTHONPATH`:

`PYTHONPATH=src python-m unittest test.api.my_test` works fine
while
`PYTHONPATH=src python -m unittest discover test` failes.

It looks like `unittest discover` does not respect `PYTHONPATH` environment variable

Comment: Using full path works for me, otherwise, relative `src` path is used which causes the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it will be useful for someone else. I deep dive into the source code of the [python extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/blob/9298b2c4fc8dc1277e2208f51b2beca4d34ca88e/pythonFiles/unittestadapter/utils.py#L238C33-L238C33) and it is revealed that there is an additional argument `--top-level-directory` / `-t` which isn't mentioned in [VS Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing).

So providing argument `-t .` to the `settings.json` file solved the issue in my case.

```
{
    ...,
    "python.testing.unittestArgs": [
        "-v",
        "-t",
        ".",
        "-s",
        "./test",
        "-p",
        "test_*.py"
    ]
}
```

As a result, command generated by the extension will look like this:

```
ms-python.python-2023.20.0/pythonFiles/unittestadapter/discovery.py --udiscovery -v -t . -s ./test -p test_*.py
```

Using `PYTHONPATH` environment variable **didn't help** as was already mentioned in one of the commentaries to the accepted answer.